# Chapter numbers in first critical note in Bible edition and other questions regarding Biblical parallel texts

Tags: reledmac, reledpar, parallel-texts

I am preparing a critical bilingual edition for a biblical book.

What I am trying to do is having the first note on each series of apparatus beginning with the number of the chapter of the book, immediately followed by the verse number of the firs lemma. For instance, if in Chapter 1 the first note refers to v. 2, the first number in the note should be 1,2; for the following notes in the same chapter, I need only the verse number to be shown.

Also, I would like to have the same layout (verse numbers instead of line numbers) for the translated text in the front page, which now has line numbers (and starts form line number 5) and get strangely high numbers in the critical notes.

The attached image is how I would like the layout to be in both pages:

1. Bible verses both in the text and in the margins (if I exclude \Xwraplinenumannotationside{@gobble} I get the verse numbers in the margins, but only for those lines where there is only one verse; otherwise I get nothing at all).
2. Chapter numbers before the verse number of the firs lemma in the critical notes.

[image]

Sorry for the Armenian, but that's the language I'm working with. For your convenience, I changed it into French in the following working file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage{english}
    \setotherlanguage{french}
\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{Arial}
    \newfontfamily\frenchfont{Arial}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[pdfusetitle,hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[noresetlinenumannotation, series={A,B,C,D}, noend,noeledsec,nofamiliar,noledgroup]{reledmac}
    \Xarrangement[A]{paragraph}
    \Xarrangement[B]{paragraph}
    \Xarrangement[C]{paragraph}
    \Xarrangement[D]{paragraph}
    \newcommand{\bv}[1]{\linenumannotation{#1}[\textbf{#1}]}
    \makeatletter
    \Xwraplinenumannotation{\@firstofone}
    \Xwraplinenumannotationside{\@gobble}
    \renewcommand{\linenumrep}[1]
    \makeatother
    \Xlinerangeseparator[B,C,D]{\nolinebreak\textnormal{--}\nolinebreak}
    \Xlinenumannotationonlyfirst
    \Xlinenumannotationonlyfirstintwo
    \Xnotenumfont[A,B,C,D]{\footnotesize \bfseries}
\Xlemmaseparator[A]{:}
    \Xinplaceoflemmaseparator{0pt}
    \Xparafootsep{ $||$ }
    \Xinplaceofnumber[A,B,C,D]{0pt}
    \Xafternote{0pt}
    \Xafternumber[A]{0pt}
    \Xtxtbeforenotes[A]{\footnotesize \textbf{\emph{Ms.\ }}}
    \setmsdatalabel{}
    \usepackage{reledpar}
    
\sloppy
\begin{document}
    \title{}
    \date{}
    \author{}
    \maketitle
    
    \begin{pages}
        \begin{Leftside}
            \begin{french}
                \beginnumbering
                    \pstart
                    \msdata{A B C} \bv{1} \edtext{Adam}{\Bfootnote{Some note}}, Seth, Énosch, \bv{2} Kénan, Mahalaleel, Jéred, \bv{3} Hénoc, Metuschélah, Lémec, \bv{4} Noé, Sem, Cham et Japhet. \bv{5} Fils de \edtext{Japhet}{\Bfootnote{Some other note}}: Gomer, Magog, \edtext{Madaï}{\Bfootnote{Some other note}}, Javan, Tubal, Méschec et Tiras. \bv{6} Fils de Gomer: \edtext{Aschkenaz}{\Cfootnote{Some note}}, Diphat et Togarma. \bv{7} Fils de Javan: Élischa, \edtext{Tarsisa}{\Cfootnote{Some ohter note}}, Kittim et Rodanim. \bv{8}Fils de Cham: Cusch, Mitsraïm, Puth et Canaan\stopmsdata{}.
                    \pend
                \endnumbering
            \end{french}    
        \end{Leftside}
        
        \begin{Rightside}
            \beginnumbering
                \pstart
                \msdata{A B C} \bv{1} \edtext{Adam}{\Bfootnote{Some comment}}, Seth, Enosh, \bv{2} Kenan, Mahalalel, Jared, \bv{3} Enoch, Methuselah, Lamech, Noah. \bv{4} The sons of Noah: Shem, Ham and Japheth. \bv{5} The sons of \edtext{Japheth}{\Bfootnote{Some other comment}}: Gomer, Magog, \edtext{Madai}{\Bfootnote{Some other comment}}, Javan, Tubal, Meshek and Tiras. \bv{6} The sons of Gomer: \edtext{Ashkenaz}{\Cfootnote{Some comment}}, Riphath[c] and Togarmah. \bv{7} The sons of Javan: Elishah, \edtext{Tarshish}{\Cfootnote{Some ohter comment}}, the Kittites and the Rodanites. \bv{8} The sons of Ham: Cush, Egypt, Put and Canaan\stopmsdata{}.
                \pend
            \endnumbering
        \end{Rightside}
    \end{pages}
    \Pages
\end{document}
```

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) :) As it stands, your code is a bit long and unwieldy. It would help us help you, if you reduced it to the essential, in the spirit of a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your desired outcome. A short text sample with a couple of dummy footnotes would suffice. Also users (like me) who don't have the font "DejaVu Serif" installed *cannot run* your code; for the sake of the MWE, you might want to switch to latin characters (as your issue is independent of the Armenian output).

Comment: Thanks for the edits and the clarifications. (I have taken the liberty to fix a couple of mistakes in the code that hindered compilation, hope that's ok.)

Comment: The one question that remains is: How do you specify the Bible chapters, how do you input them? Do you create a custom command \bch (similar to \bv) where you *input the chapter number* **manually**? Do you place a \section, or \chapter, that has the advantage of **automatic** *numbering*, but would probably complicate the layout? This is important to know, bc it makes a big difference in the possible solutions. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I’m experimenting with both your suggestions, but I guess the more convenient solution (at least for me) is to create a custom command \bch. This works well in the text, but I still can’t print the chapter number before the first footnote of the chapter. I’ll try to find a solution and come back here whenever I have (or have not!) one :)

Comment: This is probably too little, too late, sorry. Question 1) is easy. `reledmac` has a built-in system for sidenotes that prints *all* sidenotes pertaining to a line (not just the 1st), with a separator if needed. See the manual, §12 for options. You should **drop** the side-note function of `\lineannotation`, i.e. you keep `\Xwraplinenumannotationside{@gobble}`, and instead **add** sidenotes: `\newcommand{\bv}[1]{\linenumannotation{#1}\ledsidenote{#1}[\textbf{#1}]}` and `\setsidenotesep{--}`. (You can customize \ledsidenote by specifying the margin of your choice: right... inner...)

Comment: Question 2) was too hard for me, no matter how I tried. Intuitively, the solution should involve (I) the reledmac parameter `\Xtxtbeforenumber[A,B,C,D]{<text>}`. This tells the program what to print before the `linenumannotation` (hence before `\bv`). (II) A counter that is reset=0 with every new `\bch` and increased +1 with every `\bv`. (III) Specially defined conditionals that determine to print <text> IFF bch=0 (in the first verse), and to drop <text> in all subsequent verses. – But I didn't have the expertise to implement it, unfortunately.